# Nested listviews

Tags: android, listview, nested

How can i nest listviews?

Code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/places_listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">


            <EditText android:id="@+id/places_search_box"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:imeOptions="actionSearch"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:hint="Search"/>

        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/places_listViewPlaces"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Where is here the error?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You don't put items like that in a ListView. You are supposed to use a ListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest ListViews, instead implement only one ListView and see the following possibilities :

- add a header and/or a footer to your ListView.
- merge your data from different sources into the same adapter via a custom BaseAdapter.